# Pointing Two AWS Lambda Functions to Same Domain

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless, serverless-plugins

I am using the serverless framework and AWS Lambdas to deploy two function with different path names (`/message` and `/subscribe`) to my subdomain at `form.example.com`.

I am using the `serverless-domain-manager` plugin for serverless and successfully configured my domain for the `/message` function using `serverless create_domain`, but since I also needed to do that for `/subscribe` I tried to follow the same process receiving messages that the domain already existed and caught an error `Error: Unable to create basepath mapping.`.

After flipping a configuration (`createRoute53Record: false`) and re-running it started to work, but now when I run `sls deploy` for my `/message` function I get the error message I used to see for `/subscribe`.

Error (from `sls deploy`):

```
layers:
  None

  Error --------------------------------------------------

  Error: Unable to create basepath mapping.


     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.
```

Here is my config for the `serverless-domain-manager`:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-domain-manager

custom:
  transactionDomain:
    dev: ${file(./local-keys.yml):transactionDomain}
    prod: ${ssm:mg-production-transaction-domain~true}
  newsletterDomain:
    dev: ${file(./local-keys.yml):newsletterDomain}
    prod: ${ssm:mg-production-newsletter-domain~true}
  apiKey:
    dev: ${file(./local-keys.yml):apiKey}
    prod: ${ssm:mg-production-api-key~true}
  customDomain:
    domainName: form.example.com
    certificateName: 'www.example.com' //sub-domain is included in the certificate
    stage: 'prod'
    createRoute53Record: true
```

Does this have to do with the deployment of two functions to the same domain? Is there a proper process to allow that to happen?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need API gateway specific features, such as usage plan. You can put two lambda behind ALB per path routing.